# Can anyone explain what this command actually do? eval "$(/Users/jsmith/anaconda/bin/conda shell.YOUR_SHELL_NAME hook)"

Tags: command-line, docker

I am trying to create a Docker container with Anaconda and some other stuff.
After installing Anaconda I need to activate it.
When I run

```
CONDA_PATH=$HOME/anaconda3
eval "$($CONDA_PATH/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
```

from my container it works. But when I include it to my Dockerfile as

```
ENV CONDA_PATH $HOME/anaconda3
RUN eval "$($CONDA_PATH/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
```

it does not.

I know that eval executes arguments as a shell command, but I am confused with wrapping "$ ()"
Can anyone explain what it actually do?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Kosh koshmariel@gmail.com
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install htop
RUN apt-get install nano
WORKDIR /home
COPY Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh /home
ENV CONDA_PATH $HOME/anaconda3
RUN bash Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $CONDA_PATH    #silent Anaconda installation without activation
#RUN eval "$($CONDA_PATH/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
RUN $CONDA_PATH/bin/conda shell.bash hook
#RUN conda init
#RUN conda install -c conda-forge -y tensorflow
CMD /bin/bash
```

Comment: No, PC with latest Ubuntu on it

Comment: The anaconda image in docker is build on Debian image. Even if you run `eval "$(/Users/jsmith/anaconda/bin/conda shell.YOUR_SHELL_NAME hook)"` in the image after running `sudo docker run -t -i continuumio/miniconda /bin/bash`, I would expect it to fail since `/Users` isn't a pre-defined path in Linux. Instead `/Users` is available in MacOS.

Comment: I had copied it from the manual which is open on my Win PC. Actually on my Debian PC I am using other commands. I will fix it in my question.

Comment: @Kosh it will eval the result/output from the subcommand, for example, *eval "$(echo echo test)"* will output "test"

Comment: Still do not get it ( Why then I can not use just '$CONDA_PATH/bin/conda shell.bash hook' ?

Comment: I am making an image with Ubuntu + htop + nano + Anaconda + Tensorflow. (I understand that the whole Anaconda is a bit excessive). But I am more interested in understanding how the activation actually works. Now the command looks like complete nonsense to me: evaluate the results of PATH_TO_ANACONDA MY_SHELL hook - I was not even able to google what is "hook" about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`eval "$(shell-command)"` will run `shell-command` and feed its *output* to the shell as a command to execute.

A *hook* in this context is a mechanism to attach custom actions to some event processed by a software.

so `$CONDA_PATH/bin/conda shell.bash hook` will probably generate a `bash` command line which, when executed, will connect Anaconda into the running `bash` process, and `eval "$($CONDA_PATH/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"` will take care of executing that command. Try running `$CONDA_PATH/bin/conda shell.bash hook` directly from a shell prompt to see what it is producing, in order to better understand what is going on. This may well help you understanding why it isn't working in the Docker context.

Answer (score 1):

It execute a bash script in order to activate the conda environment. If you want to create a Docker image with Anaconda installed and conda environment activated, in the Dockerfile you just need to add anaconda path to the PATH environment variable. (It specifies the directories in which executable programs* are located)

```
RUN /bin/bash ~/Anaconda3-2020.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p
ENV PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH
```

$CONDA_DIR usually is:

```
/home/$USER/anaconda3/bin
```

So, when the container starts, your conda env will be available

Answer (score 0):

As [bac0n](https://askubuntu.com/users/986805/bac0n) has answered [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254371/can-anyone-explain-what-this-command-actually-do-eval-users-jsmith-anaconda/1254406#comment2119000_1254371):

> It will eval the result/output from the subcommand.
>
> For example, `eval "$(echo echo test)"` will output `test`.

(Reproduced here with modified formatting.)